# Como obrigar o .htaccess a direcionar uma subdominio dentro de uma pasta?

Tags: htaccess, apache

Eu não entendo muito do .htaccess do apache, por isso gostaria de perguntar aos colegas se é possivel o que vou explicar, tenho um dominio: mycard.com.br e um subdominio teste.mycard.com.br a pasta do dominio é /home/mycard/html já a pasta do subdominio é /home/mycard/html/subdominios/teste.

Eu queria que o usuario não entrasse no subdominio pelo link http://mycard.com.br/subdominios/teste e sim pelo http://teste.mycard.com.br

Se ele digitar: http://mycard.com.br/subdominios
ou http://mycard.com.br/subdominios/teste

Eu poderia colocar um arquivo de redirecionamento nessas pastas, mas se ele digitar http://mycard.com.br/subdominios/teste/index.php ele acessa e isso eu não queria

Ele seria redirecionado para http://teste.mycard.com.br

É possivel fazer isso pelo .htaccess?

O ideal seria criar os subdominios no mesmo nivel da pasta html, mas não tenho acesso ao vhosts do apache o servidor locaweb cria a pasta de subdominios dentro de html

Comment: E onde vai redirecionar se ele digitar `http://mycard.com.br/subdominios`?

Comment: http://mycard.com.br

Comment: e se ele digitar http://mycard.com.br/subdominios/teste
ele deve ir para  http://teste.mycard.com.br

Comment: Além disso, o subdomínio `http://mycard.com.br/subdominios/foo` tem que redirecionar para `foo.mycard.com.br` ou `teste.mycard.com.br`?

Comment: Isso, se for a pasta subdominios ele deve ir para o site principal http://mycard.com.br e se for uma subpasta ele deve ir para o http://foo.mycard.com.br

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```python
RewriteEngine On

# http://mycard.com.br/subdominios  -->  http://mycard.com.br
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mycard\.com\.br$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^subdominios/?$ / [R=301,NC,L]

# http://mycard.com.br/subdominios/nome  -->  http://nome.mycard.com.br
# http://mycard.com.br/subdominios/nome/exemplo.html  -->  http://nome.mycard.com.br/exemplo.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mycard\.com\.br$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^subdominios/([^/]+)(/.*)? http://$1.mycard.com.br$2 [R=302,NC,L]
```