# Direcionando subdomínio (htaccess) para o CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

estou com um problema que está me dando dor de cabeça..

Possuo um domínio, e então a partir dele eu gerei um subdomínio.
Este subdomínio está dentro da minha public_html, então consigo acessar por colocar /nomedosubdominio

Porém, queria que ele fizesse parte do subdomínio.. por exemplo www.subdominio.dominio.com.br

Testei uns 20 tipos de .htaccess diferente, mas não consegui fazer funcionar. Alguém pode me ajudar? Obrigado

Comment: Você tem acesso aos arquivos de configuração do Apache?

Comment: infelizmente nao.. usando a hostinger ;s

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como obrigar o .htaccess a direcionar uma subdominio dentro de uma pasta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/257213/como-obrigar-o-htaccess-a-direcionar-uma-subdominio-dentro-de-uma-pasta)

Comment: ainda assim nao consegui fazer funcionar..

Comment: as vezes até direciona para o sub-domínio, mas acaba não pegando os arquivos do diretório..

Comment: Estou com um projeto em codeigniter, dentro da public_html, com um htacces proprio pra ele.. e tenho nesta pasta public_html outra pasta, que é um outro projeto todo com as importações do code igniter e um novo .htaccess, é isso que pode dar problema será?

Comment: Sei fazer isso somente editando os arquivos de configuração do Apache, como você usa a hospedagem da Hostinger aconselho a entrar em contato com eles. Os rapazes do suporte são bem atenciosos, vale a pena tentar.

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa ir nas configuração de seu DNS (cloudflare, registro.br, godaddy, dynadot) e adicionar um alias para seu subdomínio dentro da configuração de DNS do domínio existente.

Além disso, dentro das configuração de vhost do seu servidor web existente (apache, nginx lighttpd entre outros), deve existir uma entrada apontado o root para a pasta de subdomínio, geralmente isso é criado pelo cpanel entre outros gerenciadores automaticamente.

Esse é um exemplo clássico de vhost de nginx escutando sobre a porta 80 que é a do navegador. Repare que a pasta raiz do domínio é  **/var/www/html** e que esse template será executado quando houver uma requisição que atenda ao server_names definidos, no caso, **www.meudominio.com** e **meudominio.com**. Portanto deverá existir também no servidor a mesma estrutura vhost para seu novo subdomínio (subdominio.meudominio.com) apontando para sua pasta raiz. Apesar da sintaxe diferente o procedimento é o mesmo para apache e demais.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name www.meudominio.com meudominio.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Por exemplo vamos dizer que seu domínio seja **meudominio.com** e você deseja abrir o subdominio **subdominio.meudominio.com**

Dentro das configurações do DNS você vai ver entradas com estas :

```
A meudominio.com  158.69.20.14 
A www             158.69.20.14
```

Ou seja www  é um subdomínio de meudominio.com e aponta para o ip de seu servidor, neste caso se quisermos adicionar um novo subdomínio, bastaria adicionar um novo alias em seu DNS, dessa forma:

```
A meudominio.com  158.69.20.14 
A www             158.69.20.14  
A subdominio      158.69.20.14
```

Dizendo que existe um alias (A) subdomínio, que aponta para o ip dessa maquina também ou até mesmo utilizar outro servidor com um ip diferente. Quando alguém efetuar uma requisição por subdominio.meudominio.com a resolução de DNS vai encaminhar a requisição para o ip apontado em seu registro de DNS, chegando no servidor de destino, o  servidor web localiza o template vhost com o server_name requisitado e atende a requisição apontando para a pasta interna definida no root de seu arquivo vhost. Geralmente ao adicionar subdomínios ao seu DNS não requer tempo de espera, uma vez que o domínio principal já foi propagado pela rede.